# [Flutter][Web] - How to restrict the focus removing from the text field when we tap on any other widgets?

Tags: flutter, textfield

In my following simple sample, I have the Textfields along with the Text and Container widgets. If we mouse to tap on the Container or Text widget when the focus is in the text field, the Textfield focus is lost.

In that case, I want the focus always remains in the Textfield until tap any other focusable widget i.e., another Textfield. Any suggestion about it? How can I achieve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: const MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: (() {})),
          IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: (() {}))
        ],
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
            const TextField(),
            const Text('Home Page'),
            Container(
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                width: 400,
                height: 100,
                child: const Center(child: Text('Container'))),
            const TextField(),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep the focus fixed unless you reactivate the focus mode every time the keyboard is closed